# Why the var count increasing in the code ?? however i mentioned if(vowel.indexOf(item !== -1))

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

Why the var count increasing in the code ?? however i mentioned if(vowel.indexOf(item !== -1)).

```js
document.write('<pre>');
function func7solve(str)
    {
        var vowel= "aeiouAEIOU";
        var arr = str.split("");
        var count = 0;
        arr.forEach(function(item)
        {
            document.write(item+"\n");
            document.write(vowel.indexOf(item)+"\n");
           document.write(count+"\n");
            if(vowel.indexOf(item !== -1))
            {
                count++;
            }
        });
        return count;
    }
     document.write(func7solve("The quick brown fox"));
document.write('</pre>');
```

Comment: `vowel.indexOf(item !== -1)` ~~> `vowel.indexOf(item) !== -1`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
if(vowel.indexOf(item) !== -1)
```

Otherwise, `vowel.indexOf(item !== -1)`
means `vowel.indexOf(true)` and it means `-1` and `-1` is actually truthy, so that's why the count got incremented.

Answer (score 1):

You miss use of the function `indexOf`. You need to use the [`indexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) function properly.

try with this:

> if(vowel.indexOf(item) !== -1)

```
document.write('<pre>');
function func7solve(str)
{
  var vowel= "aeiouAEIOU";
  var arr = str.split("");
  var count = 0;
  arr.forEach(function(item){
    document.write(item+"\n");
    document.write(vowel.indexOf(item)+"\n");
    document.write(count+"\n");
    if(vowel.indexOf(item) !== -1){
      count++;
    }
  });
  return count;
}
document.write(func7solve("The quick brown fox"));
document.write('</pre>');
```